# I'm asking a question about my own post, but I'm still prompted that I need 5 reputation to post here. What gives?

Tags: support, asking-questions, meta, new-users, faq-proposed

I had a meta question about one of my own posts on the main site.

Someone (a user, a help page, etc.) told me that while I ordinarily need 5 reputation to post on this Meta site, I can ask a question about one of my own posts without needing reputation.

However, after I've entered the link to my question on the main site, proceeded to type up my meta question here, and tried to post it, the system suddenly prompts me that I need 5 reputation to post here. I thought I could post here without needing 5 reputation if I use that form, and everything pointed to that fact, but why am I suddenly told I need 5 reputation only *after* I've fully typed up my question and tried to post it?

Is there something wrong with my question, with the way it's written, or something to that effect? When I clicked the button to review my question, it didn't say anything was wrong with it.

<sub>Meta.SE bug report: [Make error message if a new user removes or misplaces the mandatory header text of meta questions about their own post more clear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327702/make-error-message-if-a-new-user-removes-or-misplaces-the-mandatory-header-text)</sub>

Comment: We've been getting a few SO-specific questions on Meta.SE, where the author asks about their question and complains that they can't ask here because of this error message. Posting this here so there's a reference guide here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This error message actually has nothing to do with reputation. You're receiving this error because the [system isn't properly seeing the header text with the link to your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327702/make-error-message-if-a-new-user-removes-or-misplaces-the-mandatory-header-text) that it's added for you when you started writing your meta question.

When you fill in the form to ask a meta question about your own post, and you get to the question asking form, you'll notice that the system has added some lines to the top of your post:

> [image: Lines added by system]

```
<!-- Do not remove or edit -->
<!-- Note: Questions not about your post will be deleted -->

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Title of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57177487/title-of-my-question)

<!-- Your question below: -->
```

When you submit your question, the system must see these pre-existing lines in the same spot, exactly as they were originally written. This means that you **must not** modify or delete these lines in any way, or type any text above them. If you don't keep these lines *exactly* as they are written, you will receive this error message.

If you're receiving this error message and can't figure out how to skip past it, the easiest way is to select and copy the question you've written, go back to the form where it asks you to enter the link to your post, re-enter your post link there, and paste your question below the "Your question below" line.

The error message is a bit cryptic here, but there's an easy way to skip past it.