# Do we have guidance for first-time askers not perceiving themselves as programmers?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, new-users

I know that we have some guidance for first-time askers, but do we have something for "non-programmers"?

I have found a lot of questions about [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets), [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) and other Google applications, starting with some variation of "I'm not a programmer", some code found somewhere, most of the time using JavaScript, but some also use HTML and CSS, and a request to change the code someway.

<sup>Note: It's clear to me that anything that the OP shares in the question body that isn't necessary to clearly communicate what is being asked is noise/chit-chat (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) and should be removed following the editing guidelines.</sup>

Sometimes the change could be done by changing a literal, adding a variable and a loop, or changing an expression. Sometimes it requires something more, but not too much work and others require a lot of work. I have found myself pointing them to the closest guide I know, i.e., [Storing the information you need - Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Variables) [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), some content from [Mozilla Developer Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDN_Web_Docs), which most of them are external posts and voting to close it as duplicate or "Unclear or needs more details".

<sup>Note: I meant most of the time I vote to close, sometimes I post an answer trying to make it easy to understand without making it a long-detailed tutorial</sup>

When the question is about a specific feature of a web application, I think that it's OK to point them to the external content, but I'm not sure about when the question requires something like implementing an algorithm or condition in a programming language like JavaScript. Providing an answer with the change requested sometimes doesn't feel to be appropriate for SO. Sometimes I suggest the change in a comment and suggest providing more details if they need further help.

I'm wondering if pointing the OP too to [What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/1595451) might be nice, but I feel that this should be done with some sort of explanation that might have been written before with the SO community collaboration.

Related:

- [I think we're pointing new users at the wrong "How to Ask" page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253356/1595451)
- [How can we encourage (new) authors to ask confident questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366264/1595451)

Comment: I've encountered an asker who, after years of asking hundreds of questions, still prefaced theirs with "I'm new to C#". To them, it was an excuse for not having to do research.

Answer (score 34):

Someone who writes code is a programmer. Their claim that they are not is false and irrelevant. If it appears in the question body, remove it just like you would with any other statement such as "I am new to Java", "I am just a beginner", "I have 130 years of experience as a developer", etc.

It doesn't help us in any way to know how much experience the question author has. It shouldn't matter anyway. We should strive to write our answers in such a way that they can be understood by any developer. That's why clear and concise explanations are the best. Their personal information is just noise and has no place on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm thinking that I will pointing these self named "no-programmers" to this answer :)

Comment: Well, 'Someone who writes code is a programmer' - if they cannot make, at least some, attempt to test/debug the code they present here, I would classify them as 'copy-paster'.

Comment: By the same token, someone who splash some colors to the paper is an artist?

Comment: @PM77-1 Probably not a very good one, but yes.

Comment: @PM77-1 Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_expressionism#/media/File:'Boon'_oil_on_canvas_painting_by_James_Brooks,_1957,_Tate_Gallery.jpg), or [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/05/Jean-Paul_Riopelle%2C_1951%2C_Untitled%2C_oil_on_canvas%2C_54_x_64.7_cm.jpg)?

Comment: As one of the newer the programming people who often asks about Apps Script, I suspect that the reason **why** to state this is different to what you might think?

I've found asking Q's on SO both fantastic, and incredibly stressful. Not because of the software, but because almost 50%+ of my interactions, I've felt like I'm being told off in some way for some transgression. 

You are right that how one percieves themself is irrelevant to the question, but it's very relevant to an ideal answer. Eg. If I don't understand arrays or objects - a correct answer may go completely over my head

Answer (score 26):

### Their self-perception is not relevant

For the people asking, we have [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/). For people answering and editing, we have https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721; [No Thanks, Damn It!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160) and more.

Putting aside any semantic argument about who is or is not "a programmer", "a beginner" etc., such observations do not belong in questions. OPs (and many answerers, too) should be reminded that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum** - one of the key implications of this is that questions need to be direct **questions** that are about **the problem, not** the person asking it, nor any aspect of that person's life experience, as "a programmer" or "a beginner" or otherwise. The person who asks the question is **not relevant** to the question.

Commentary that is irrelevant to the question should be removed. Questions should be edited to ask the question as *clearly, directly and explicitly* as possible; this is more important as the question gains popularity and "frequency" (i.e.: other questions closed as a duplicate of it).

If the change that is needed is simple, that does not exclude the question from being suitable for the site. If the change that is needed can be understood by following a tutorial, that also does not *necessarily* exclude the question (although it is always fine to suggest in the comments, **politely**, following a tutorial to those who would benefit).

The question **is** unsuitable **if**:

- it has been asked before: please vote to close questions as duplicates. IMHO it is also appropriate to *be more liberal in the interpretation of "duplicate" the simpler the question is* - because simple questions are, inherently, asked by people who are less capable of expressing them clearly (more charitably: asked in more creative ways by people who mistakenly believe their circumstance is special).
- it is multiple questions in one, *even if not phrased that way*. In other words, if there are multiple issues with the code that is shown. Such a question "needs more focus". Generally, this includes cases where OP is treating Stack Overflow as a code-writing or [homework-doing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822) service; a *task* description is not a *problem*, and therefore a *request* to have a task performed is not a *question* - but instead, an implication of multiple questions.
- it can be answered *using knowledge/understanding already demonstrated in the question*, or by applying basic logic/reasoning below the level of what is already demonstrated. This is admittedly a somewhat broad interpretation on my part, but it's what "not reproducible or caused by a typo" is meant to capture (and why we used to call it "too localized" before everyone decided that that, too, was being misinterpreted). The point is: questions like this can't help other people, because it's practically impossible to get into the same spot in an organic way - OP's reason for being stuck is a failure to apply basic debugging techniques, take a break if necessary, and think clearly. (Note that it is [perfectly fine to ask a question that is well below your own level](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). The criterion here is the *content of the question post*, not anything about the person asking. Again: the person asking is **not relevant** to the question.)
- it does not make sense to ask, and appears to be based in a misconception that can't readily be turned into a clear, explicit question. Such a question "needs details or clarity". Typically, this entails someone asking to do something that's both impossible and nonsensical on its face; while there *might* be a possible, reasonable thing to do underlying that question, and even though that might be what OP actually wants to know about, questions like this typically leave doubt as to *what* task is actually underlying the impossible request. This situation can also come about [because of an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).
- Someone wants to solve a problem without actually writing code. Questions about using Google Sheets are only on topic insofar as they involve, at some point in the process, writing code. Spreadsheet formulas [are](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261875) code. A "specific feature of [a] web app" is probably not.

In other words: questions should be closed when they fit into the stated reasons for closing questions. They aren't perfect (and I have many complaints), but they are pretty good. The rules apply the same to questions that start with a disclaimer about skill level, as to questions that don't, because - once more - that is information about the person asking the question, who is **not relevant** to the question.

Answer (score 14):

Absent any fancy moniker or title, the expectations for people asking questions doesn't change:

- The question needs to be on-topic for the site
- The question needs to be clear, concise and understandable
- The question needs to have all of the information in the question itself, with no off-site linking, and all error messages applicable

Whether or not the answers we provide turn into a lot of work to implement for someone asking that of us is, frankly, orthogonal to the answering of the question.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. What I tried to say is that besides voting/editing I leave a comment pointing the OP to something "helpful" I'm wondering if there is something that addresses this self-naming practice that I could include in the comment.

Answer (score 6):

Being a programmer is a matter of attitude, not experience. A programmer can be new and serious, or experienced and unserious. My main issue when people ask questions (not just here, but elsewhere), is when people use inexperience as a way to *not* be detailed and direct in their question asking.

To put it a bit differently, I would much rather have a *serious* programmer who is inexperienced (which itself is relative) ***clearly*** ask a question with a MWE than an unserious experienced programmer who's asking a question but gives no data/code to work with. So, people of any skill level should feel completely confident asking questions, *on condition* that they're asking questions in the right way.

Comment: Some users use inexperience as a plea for tolerance / empathy with their ignorance... they might simple not know how to be detailed and direct in proper way, among other reasons. Anyway, what do you do on posts claiming inexperience? Do you give some guidance?

Comment: What I usually do (on other websites, such as Statalist) is I redirect the OP to a question I asked which a) clearly asks my question, b) provides synthetic/the real dataset I'm working with, and  c) provides the verbatim code that I used which reproduces the error I'm having. That way, the OP has a better idea of what kinds of questions get the best and most helpful responses and can reformat accordingly. @Rubén

Comment: Thanks. It's a good idea to point first-time askers to good examples. I suggest you to mention that in your answer. P.S. On SO we have a vote to "close as duplicate". Ideally, the original question should work as good examples of how to ask a question but here the emphasis on pointing to an already available answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tl;Dr. Just ask the OP to take SO seriously, not as a place for posting an ephemeral contribution as they might do on their social networks / having a small chat in a social gathering, but be warned that comments like this very frequently are not well received by the OP and lurkers.

---

The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask), [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/off-topic), [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer) and maybe other materials should be easy to read by anyone able to post here, no matter of their background or programming skills. As these materials are already linked on ask-page, answer-page, etc., rather than pointing the first timer to someplace, we should ask them to take the posting action seriously. Also you might suggest them to post in Meta, including a link to their first post.

From an reviewer mindset it's a waste of time trying to guess why the OP added "noise" / "chit-chat" in the question. In most cases the statements about the OP person and their context should be removed from a question / answer. One exception among others might be when they explain their role when it's relevant from a programming perspective, never to justify their lack of knowledge and skills or time to write a good question (or answer).

Related

- [On being nice and still not feeding the trolls or help vampires or whatever](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374634/1595451)
- [I'm asking a question about my own post, but I'm still prompted that I need 5 reputation to post here. What gives?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400064/1595451)