# What's wrong with my post? It didn't get reponses and it got downvoted

Tags: support, specific-question

I don't use Stack Overflow much, but now I have started using it lately. I posted this question, and I’m getting no much response. Also I'm getting downvoted, and I don't know why.

Even though the problem seems simple, it's just an interface implementation that I am stuck with, but nobody is answering me with a good answer.

*[How do I properly implement the ZKTeco IZKEM interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909302/new-to-c-sharp-and-zkteco-sdk-and-i-am-having-trouble-with-the-implementation-of)*

Comment: people are interacting with you in the comment section so you are getting *response*

Comment: Which of your questions are you asking about here? If you're asking about your question that was initially titled [New to C# and ZKTeco Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73909302/new-to-c-sharp-and-zkteco-sdk-and-i-am-having-trouble-with-the-implementation-of) then the title alone is going to likely attract downvotes; the title is to tell us about the question not how new you are to technologies.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I meant no solutions

Comment: Images of error/code/data etc are also often very poorly received. Have a read of the FAQ on why: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It is an example of the XY problem.  You assumed the problem was caused by you being new to C#.  Contributors took your word for it, re-inforced by a code snippet that is missing the code that did not compile.  None of this helped them identify the real issue, a very poorly designed library that gives any programmer a throbbing headache.  All the info necessary to arrive at an answer is actually present but cutting through that kind of clutter is just very hard to do.  So not getting an answer is unsurprising.

Comment: If you are new to C# and getting stonewalled by this sort of error message, **learn the fundamentals of C# first** rather than trying to deal with someone else's library that is apparently not very well known.

Comment: Yep, about the "Form",  the Title stroke me directly as well, we don't care about your life + level, especially in a Title, ([interesting reading](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420621/3799241) about that), has been corrected now, the new Title is just perfect. // And Code or Runtime/Compile Errors as Images is also always a "Recipe" for Downvotes. (Not corrected yet.) // The Follow-up (lack of or slow => also often a Reason for Downvotes) on the Question was good... // I can't say much about the "Content", except that you seem to have several Questions in the same Thread...

Comment: This is 'Meta' not 'Main', and closing this Thread for 'details or clarity' feels to me like the Closers are "misusing" their Close Priviledge, I found it "*funny*" for the '[Collectives Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/420537/timeline)', well done, funny Joke...!, but not "here", the @OP is genuinely trying to get some Feedback and to improve their Question on 'Main', the Question is "clear", and the Link to the Question on 'Main' is included, the User is following up neatly, I don't see what more "Details" would be needed...!?

Comment: Yeah well, not only for your "*futur[e] Posts*" but for this one already, and you need to (fairly quickly) act upon Feedback/Comments/Answers... :idea: // About the Title, you posted some "*I will try to change the title*" but didn't do anything about it, and some 8k-User had to do the Edit for you 1h later... // About the Errors as Images, 18h later, still nothing has happened about that, while you've even accepted an Answer (here on Meta) about that part, => +2 extra more Downvvotes (since my previous Comments), and the Question on 'Main' now got also closed, in the last 2h...

Comment: @chivracq I will be quick to respond, I did change the title in my main post, I did not change the errors as images because the question has been closed anyway and also visual studio does not allow me to copy error messages so I have to re-write them unless im missing something so I will figure it out, about the title of this post in meta I don't know what to change in it really it seems fine.

Comment: Oh yep, you're right about the Title (on Main), you had already edited it, and the 8k-User edited it after you into some "even better" Title... Sorry, I missed that part... // Well about re-typing the Errors, if the Visual Studio GUI doesn't allow for a Copy_to_Clipboard (I'm a bit surprised, but that could be, MS can be a "PITA" for that indeed), then well, re-typing those is the "small price to pay" to get your Questions received "positively" on SO, ah-ah...! (+ Will help other Users getting the same Error(s)...)

Comment: yes, I agree I will do that, I will type the errors using '>' I think it will be more helpful, Thank you @chivracq

Comment: Re *"Visual Studio does not allow me to copy error messages"*: I doubt that (normal meaning of "doubt"). But it may be hidden. Just Ctrl + C (with or without a selection) works in many cases (sort of a hidden feature). In many dialogs on Windows, just Ctrl + C (without a selection) while the dialog is in focus will copy the text to the clipboard. That is *at least* the case for the [ASSERT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_(software_development)#Assertions_for_run-time_checking) dialogs (say, from a .NET application developed under Visual Studio) and I think also most of the views -

Comment: cont' - inside Visual Studio (some may or may not require a selection).

Comment: Mapping out different (non-obvious) ways of copying text in different software development environments is an idea for a meta post or blog post. Then we could point to that. It would be one less excuse to use images for text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quality of the responses you get is in part a function of the quality of your question. Being clear and concise in asking your questions, giving people all of the info they need, and *in particular* supplementing your query through *code*, not images, is particularly helpful. Put another way: we want you to help us help you.

At the moment we're typing on computers—and we can't get errors, code, or other helpful information from images. So providing minimal reproducible examples and showing some level of interaction with software is typically the difference between queries that get effective feedback and others that do not.